# Paypal - Auto-calculate shipping charges not working

Tags: php, paypal, sdk, paypal-sandbox

i have config Shipping methods in my account. 
When I change shipping address, it does not add shipping price as I have set up.
[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3v3a.png)
[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xL8mT.png)

```
$itemList->setShippingMethod('Standard International'); 
$transaction = new Transaction(); 
$transaction->setAmount($amount);
$transaction->setItemList($itemList);
```

Comment: Did you check the post data?

Comment: @mapmalith I didn't think I was wrong. https://imgur.com/a/AVQe81i